# How to work with the queue using the task factory

Tags: c#, multithreading

There is a queue. There is a function that processes messages from this queue. This function takes the message from the queue, start new task to process the next message, waiting data from other sources, and then carries out the calculation.

**This is example**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestTaskFactory
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Data = 50;
        static int ActiveTasksNumber = 0;
        static int MaxActiveTasksNumber = 0;

        static Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();

        static object locker = new object();
        static object locker2 = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            clock.Start();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork());

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }

        public static void DoWork()
        {
            //imitation of geting message from some queue
            int message = GetMessageFromQueue();

            lock (locker2)
            {
                ActiveTasksNumber++;
                MaxActiveTasksNumber = Math.Max(MaxActiveTasksNumber,
                                                  ActiveTasksNumber);
                Console.Write("\r" + message + "   ");
            }

            //Run new task to work with next message
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork());

            //imitation wait some other data
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            //imitation of calculations with message
            int tmp = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 30000000; i++)
            {
                tmp = Math.Max(message, i);
            }

            lock (locker2)
            {
                ActiveTasksNumber--;
            }
        }

        public static int GetMessageFromQueue()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (Data == 0)
                {
                    //Queue is empty. All tasks completed except one 
                    //that is waiting for new data
                    clock.Stop();

                    Console.WriteLine("\rMax active tasks number = "
                        + MaxActiveTasksNumber
                        + "\tTime = " + clock.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
                    Console.Write("Press key to run next iteration");

                    clock.Reset();

                    Console.ReadKey();

                    Console.Write("                                       ");

                    //In queue received new data. Processing repeat
                    clock.Start();

                    ActiveTasksNumber = 0;
                    MaxActiveTasksNumber = 0;
                    Data = 50;
                }

                Data--;
                return Data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My guess, when the queue is empty, all tasks are completed except one task that awaits the new data. When data arrives in the queue the calculations are repeated.

But if you look at the results , every time the number of simultaneously running tasks increases.

**Why is this happening?**

**Test results**

[image]

Comment: Well, the number displayed will never *decrease*, because you're computing and displaying the max. The reason it's increasing probably has to do with the fact that the first thing your worker does is spawn another task. Your code will create a new task for every item in the queue. You need to limit the number of concurrent tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is wrong.

First of all, where is your Queue?
For any jobs you want to queue in a concurrent environment, use the ConcurrentQueue.

The concurrent queue, is used in this fashion, it doesn't need to be locked at any time.

```
// To create your Queue
ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

// To add objects to your Queue
queue.Enqueue("foo");

// To deque items from your Queue    
String bar;
queue.TryDequeue(out bar);

// To loop a process until your Queue is empty
while(!queue.IsEmpty)
{
    String bar;
    queue.TryDequeue(out bar);
}
```

Next is how you are incrementing and decrementing your counters, there is a far better way of doing it which is thread safe. Again, the data doesn't need to be locked.

```
// Change your data type from int to long
static long ActiveTasksNumber = 0;
static long MaxActiveTasksNumber = 0;

// To increment the values in a Thread safe fashion:
Interlocked.Increment(ref ActiveTasksNumber);

// To decrement:
Interlocked.Decrement(ref MaxActiveTasksNumber);
```

Implement what I've shown you, and it should make your problems disappear

Edit: 
Namespaces

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
```

Comment: The question is not how to implement a queue. It does not matter. The question is: Why when I again set data = 50. Task factory runs more than 14 tasks, as in the first iteration. And their number is growing with each iteration. Although I understand the number of simultaneously running tasks controlled by tasks factory to maximize using of system resources. This number may vary, but not in such as in result.

Comment: I think I found the answer: This particular work task factory. If you run my example and make pause between iterations 10 seconds, then the result will be, what I expected to see. It is strange that if you do not make a pause, the result will be unpredictable.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself tempted to use `ConcurrentQueue`, reach instead for [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx). It's almost always the preferred choice. It's a `ConcurrentQueue` underneath, but it has a much nicer API that's a lot easier to work with. For example, it does non-busy waits, provides a consuming `IEnumerable`, supports cancelation, etc. Learn it, love it.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment:

You have, in essence, this:

```
public static void DoWork()
{
    // imitation of geting message from some queue
    int message = GetMessageFromQueue();

    // Run new task to work with next message
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork());

    // do some work
}
```

Your code is going to get the first message, start a task to work with the next item, and then do its work. While the first task is working, the second gets an item and spawns yet another task to get an item from the queue. So now you have two threads supposedly doing work and a third that's going to spawn yet another, etc . . .

Nothing in your code stops it from creating a new task for every item in the queue.

If your queue started with 38 things, it's highly likely that you'll end up with 38 concurrent tasks.

You need to limit the number of tasks you're running at the same time. There are many ways to do that. Perhaps the easiest is a simple producer-consumer model using [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You are right, but how to find the optimal limit of concurrent tasks? I thought it would make the task factory. For example, 35 task requests a factory run 36 task, but the factory decides that it is not enough free resources and start the 36 task when one of the previous tasks completed. Thus the system will be used most efficiently. Or not? I do not know how to find the optimal limit of concurrent tasks manually. Because it is impossible to predict in advance how long every task will be idle waiting for external resources, and do not know the number of available computer resources.

Comment: @ArturNikkonen: A good initial guess is the number of cores you have. So if your computer has 4 CPU cores, then limit it to 4 concurrent tasks.

Comment: I changed a little test program: Increased Queue to 5000 and made calculations longer in comparison with the waiting time. As a result, on my core i7 I got the following result: Max number of concurrent tasks = 29, average number of concurrent taxes = 22. I think this is a good result, which shows that the choice of the maximum number of concurrent tasks can be trusted to factory. I think this is a better way than try to limit the number of tasks manually. I still experiment and write about the results. I want to make the factory to run too many tasks that it affected to performance.

Comment: After a night of tests, I came to the following conclusion, that any manual limitation of concurrency level reduces the performance of the program (excluding specific situation with a huge number of short tasks). Strange results that I described in the question, are explained by that the tasks factory slowly starts new threads (several per second) and is also slowly killing them. Therefore, each next iteration begins with a large number of threads and run faster. If wait enough time until factory kill all processes after iteration, the results of each iteration will be the same.